# Using call <file.bat> results in "sleep is not recognized as an internal or external command.."

Tags: batch-file, cmd, call

I have a script that calls other commands in a for loop:

```
for %%x in (%CMDS::= %) do (
  call C:\%%x %1%
  echo "%%x complete"
)
```

However, running this results the console spitting out :

```
'sleep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This is because the files i loop through and run have these commands in them. Why is it that if i run these files one by one they work, but when chained using `call` they don't? I can `sleep` in my terminal outside of this script..

Regards

Comment: Considering you call it terminal, are you sure you're using `cmd` and not, say, `bash`?

Comment: @Joey Yes, sorry. Fixing it I mean `cmd` (as in .bat, .cmd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `sleep` command in batch. That's why you are getting this error.

EDIT:
There is no `sleep` command in Windows CMD or Batch. BUT: as you can use the command in your console, I suppose there might be a script or a program called `sleep`. This script or program might be situated in your **working directory** or in some other directory included in your `%PATH%` variable. If this is the case, it's possible that your script gives you this error because of a path issue.

Say, you are in `C:\SomeFolder` and there is a `sleep.exe` in there. You are calling another script or command which changes the current directory to `D:\AnotherFolder`. Now another script or command tries to execute your mysterious `sleep` command assuming the working dir to be `C:\SomeFolder` but as you are in a different folder (`D:\SnotherFolder`) now, `sleep` can't be found. Further, when using `call` the variable scope of the calling script becomes also the scope for the called script. So it's also possible that variables are being overwritten by different scripts. Such a variable might contain the path to your sleep command. This could also cause an error.

Comment: Yet if i do `sleep 5` the console window sleeps.. How then do I chain these scripts to make them run as call if they were called one by one?

Comment: THERE IS NO SLEEP COMMAND IN WINDOWS CMD / BATCH.

Comment: Nevermind, sleep was powershell. I retract that sleep works. However, the scripts im calling all depend on it, so I assume, since they work, that they have access to these commands.

Comment: @enrm Now we're talking :) But the problem is: your BATCH file is trying to execute `sleep` command. And as it is a PowerShell command, it gives you an error. Can't help you without seeing the other scripts. Have you checked possible path issues as described in my edited post?

Comment: I just found out the folder where the scripts are running contain a `sleep.exe`. I'm sorry for the confusion. So I just have to cd to the path before running the script? Because i want to have it on my desktop but run it in C:\scripts for example?

Comment: You don't have to change directory, just change `sleep.exe` to `"%~dp0sleep.exe"`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46071092/5362795), I solved this error by replacing `sleep 5` in my `.bat` file with:

```
powershell -Command "& {sleep 5}"
```

Works fine now. Better still, also tested Stephan's suggestion:

```
timeout 5
```

Simpler, and shows a nice message like

> Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

Note that some Windows versions require the `/t` option to define the time.

```
timeout /t 5
```

Comment: no need to employ PowerShell. Simply replace the `sleep` with `timeout` (see `timeout /?`) (PS: `sleep.exe` once was part of the 2003 resource kit)

Comment: I see, I'd have removed it if someone gave me a reason :) I left it to keep my original answer for context and extra info, who knows, it might be useful in some cases. Very often search engines take me to SO and I find useful answers that may deviate slightly from the OP's question. Anyway, I rarely do Windows stuff and I just used this in a casual personal utility script so whatever works is fine. Thanks for the extra tip, I actually like the countdown, it's cool and informative.

Comment: I like both answers since the powershell one doesn't have specialized output. While the timeout tells you how long you have left. You can also add `/NOBREAK` to the `timeout` to not risk the next command being unintentionally executed early. The powershell command doesn't need the extra update.

Comment: There is one reason to still use `sleep` over `timeout`. `sleep` has the `-m` option which allows you to specify the time in milliseconds. `timeout` does not have such an option.