# How to run powershell command in batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

```
@ECHO off

$BIOS= Get-WmiObject -computername "BAHRIATSG2-PC" -Namespace 
root/hp/instrumentedBIOS -Class HP_BIOSSettingInterface

$BIOS.SetBIOSSetting('Setup Password','<utf-16/>TheBIOSPassword','<utf-16/>')

pause
```

when i save as .bat file and run it does not working  otherwise it is working properly in powershell when i entering manually..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a PowerShell script from a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335004/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-from-a-batch-file)

Comment: I'm not sure the duplicate question quite explains it. You need to save your script as a .ps1 file and then you could execute it from the a .bat script as described in the above linked question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute powershell commands from a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037146/how-to-execute-powershell-commands-from-a-batch-file)

Comment: Of course it will work fine in Powershell.  It is powershell code.  You can't expect CMD.exe to interpret some other scripting languages code and be able to execute it.  That goes for ALL scripting languages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Enclose your PowerShell code in,

```
powershell -Command "& {}"
```

Remember to separate all statements with `;` and to enclose your `"` with a quoted string, i.e by using `""`

```
powershell -Command "& {$BIOS= Get-WmiObject -computername ""BAHRIATSG2-PC\"" -Namespace root/hp/instrumentedBIOS -Class HP_BIOSSettingInterface; $BIOS.SetBIOSSetting('Setup Password','<utf-16/>TheBIOSPassword','<utf-16/>')}"
```

Comment: In case anyone else runs across this, as I did -- It may help to use `foreach-object` instead of the `%` alias when executing a command like this. 
 Otherwise, it may result in an `Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline` error.

Comment: I am trying to "escape" strings like you said in this command without any luck. can you help me please? `(netsh wlan show profiles) | Select-String "\:(.+)$" | %{$name=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{(netsh wlan show profile name="$name" key=clear)}  | Select-String "Key Content\W+\:(.+)$" | %{$pass=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{[PSCustomObject]@{ PROFILE_NAME=$name;PASSWORD=$pass }} | Format-Table -AutoSize`

Answer (score 7):

I think [this is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672784/convert-a-small-ps-script-into-a-long-line-in-a-batch-file) the simplest and clearest way because it don't requires any superfluous switch; just plain PowerShell code:

```
@ECHO off

PowerShell ^
   $BIOS= Get-WmiObject -computername \"BAHRIATSG2-PC\" -Namespace;  ^ 
   root/hp/instrumentedBIOS -Class HP_BIOSSettingInterface;  ^
   $BIOS.SetBIOSSetting('Setup Password','<utf-16/>TheBIOSPassword','<utf-16/>')

pause
```

Just add a `; ^` at end of each line except the last line and escape each quote with backslash.

Answer (score 2):

Following this thread: 
https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/converting-powershell-to-batch



**you can convert any PowerShell script into a batch file easily using this PowerShell function:**

```
function Convert-PowerShellToBatch
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]
        [Alias("FullName")]
        $Path
    )
 
    process
    {
        $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Path $Path -Raw -Encoding UTF8)))
        $newPath = [Io.Path]::ChangeExtension($Path, ".bat")
        "@echo off`npowershell.exe -NoExit -encodedCommand $encoded" | Set-Content -Path $newPath -Encoding Ascii
    }
}
```

To convert **all** PowerShell scripts inside a directory, simply run the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path <DIR-PATH> -Filter *.ps1 |
  Convert-PowerShellToBatch
```

Where  is the path to the desired folder. For instance:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\path\to\powershell\scripts" -Filter *.ps1 |
  Convert-PowerShellToBatch
```

To convert a **single** PowerShell script, simply run this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path <FILE-PATH> |
  Convert-PowerShellToBatch
```

Where  is the path to the desired file.


The converted files are located in the source directory. i.e., *<FILE-PATH>* or *<DIR-PATH>*.

Answer (score 1):

powershell has its own script file type, extension is .ps1

Save your code to a .ps1 file, and run it from a batch file with:

powershell xxx.ps1