# Run Powershell Command from Batch File to Rename Network Drive

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file to rename network drives, since 'Label' does not work.  I have created a PS1 script which works, but I am trying to get the script into a single Batch file so I can run handle several sequential non-powershell commands.  My PS1 is as follows:

```
$ShellObject = New-Object –ComObject Shell.Application
$DriveMapping = $ShellObject.NameSpace('Z:')
$DriveMapping.Self.Name = 'DataStore'
```

My current Batch File command is as follows:

```
powershell -Command " $ShellObject = New-Object –ComObject Shell.Application; $DriveMapping = $ShellObject.NameSpace('Z:'); $DriveMapping.Self.Name = 'DataStore'"
```

Which gives me the following error:

[Powershell CLI Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qcE8.png)

The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set...

My original reference on how to approach this was from here:[How to run powershell command in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070152/how-to-run-powershell-command-in-batch-file) which included the ampersand.

When I could not get it to work I then tried the format here:[Run powershell command from cmd](https://superuser.com/questions/1080239/run-powershell-command-from-cmd)

At this point I have tried a few different arrangements of semi-colons, quotes, apostrophes, etc without any success.  This seems like a simple problem and appreciate any help offered.

Comment: Have you checked to see if `$DriveMapping` is $null? That is what happens here.

Comment: Thinking outside the box on this and is something I have never tried. Is it possible to create the PS1 file via a batch file, execute the PS1 file with PS calling the PS1 file, and then delete the PS1 that was created?

Comment: I just ran the above command and then I ran, `powershell -Command "$DriveMapping -ne $null"` 'False'.  So I do not think the value is null. @lit

Comment: @Backin I like that suggestion as as a work around, I'll remember it if I cannot get the translation between the CLI and PS to work out.  Thanks.

Comment: Does the three (3) line PowerShell script run as expected from a .ps1 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$DriveMapping` variable always comes out `$null` here.

```
C:>type drivemap.bat
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$ShellObject = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application;" ^
    "$DriveMapping = $ShellObject.NameSpace('Z:');" ^
    "$DriveMapping -eq $null;" ^
    "$DriveMapping.Self.Name = 'DataStore'"
```

Therefore, the `Name` property is not available.

```
C:>powershell -NoProfile -Command     "$ShellObject = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application;"     "$DriveMapping = $ShellObject.NameSpace('Z:');"     "$DriveMapping -eq $null;"     "$Drive
Mapping.Self.Name = 'DataStore'"
True
The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:128
+ ... 'Z:'); $DriveMapping -eq $null; $DriveMapping.Self.Name = 'DataStore'
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Variables such as `$DriveMapping` do not persist across PowerShell invocations. When PowerShell is run again, the `$DriveMapping` variable does not exist.

Comment: Expand the question to ask, is there a way to use PowerShell at the CLI so that the second call for $DriveMapping occurs during the first invocation?

Comment: A second invocation of PowerShell starts afresh. It does not know about any variables from a different invocation of PowerShell. Is that what you are asking?